# Equivalent of sp_lock, sp_who for mysql

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please tell me what is the equivalent of sp_lock, sp_who or sp_who2 in mysql server? Basically I want to know which tables are locked due to some query and which host is holding on to those exclusive locks.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's old now, but check out this site for troubleshooting tips: https://web.archive.org/web/20161105125007/http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/

Comment: above link do not work

Comment: The link above does not work, but the Internet Archive (at web.archive.org) has logged the information at:
https://web.archive.org/web/20161105125007/http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/

Answer (score 5):

Not the same, but similar for sp_who:

SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST